# Issues with the use of CSS modules in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to use CSS modules in React but faced this error:

```
Failed to compile.
./src/components/Header/Header.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './Header.module.css' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\qwerty\qwerty-project\src\components\Header'
```

Here is the code I am using

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Header.module.css";
const header = props => {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <i className="fab fa-github"></i>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <nav>
          <ul className={styles.nav}>
            <li>{props.home}</li>
            <li>{props.about}</li>
            <li>{props.contact}</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default header;
```

Comment: @ChristianMoen You are wrong. `Header.module.css` is a valid name.

Comment: @user9408899, please can you help this error is killing me. What can be the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide the code of `Header.module.css` file? So it will be helpful for us.

Comment: Its working for me. Look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-knuth-keh6u). I am using create-react-app, if you are not using CRA then you need to use babel plugin `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` to support css modules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CSS file as a module you will need to use a webpack loader.

Alternatively you can just `import "./Header.module.css";` and use the classnames to style your components